# AWS Policy deny access on all production resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-policies, aws-roles

In our team, we have both our production and development stack in the same AWS account. These stacks are distinguished by their resource name. For example, we have a S3 bucket `example-dev-bucket` and `example-prod-bucket` . Al these resources are thus also distinguishable by their arn, e.g. `arn:aws:s3:::example-dev-bucket` and `arn:aws:s3:::example-prod-bucket` . Now I want to create an IAM role that grants access to all resources except for production resources.

To grant access to all resources is easy, I add a policy with the following statement

```
Effect: Allow
Action:
  - '*'
Resource:
  - '*'
```

After allowing all resources, I want to add a policy to deny the production resources. Only doing this for S3 resources works fine, like below.

```
Effect: Deny
Action:
  - '*'
Resource:
  - 'arn:aws:s3:::*-prod-*'
```

However, doing this for multiple services all at once, does not seem to be valid syntax. I have tried something like `*-prod-*` and `arn:aws:*:*:*:*:*-prod-*`.

A possible solution for me is to add each service just like I added the S3 service. However, it's easy to forget services. Rather I would just have a single line that includes all resources that have `-prod-` in their arn.

Comment: the best would be to work with tags: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-policy-tags-deny/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The resources are not yet distinguishable by tags. It would be a good practice for us to add these, but for now this will be too much work as I would need to add a tag for each resource. If possible, I would rather find a way of selecting resources based on their arn.

Comment: Don't mix production and development systems in the same AWS account. That should be a sev 1 ticket in any organization.

Comment: Seperating environments is next on our wishlist. Unfortunately, this will be quite some work.

Comment: Investigate what high-level constraints you can configure, in that case. AWS Organization-level Service Control Policies and IAM Permissions Boundaries are relevant here, as both can constrain the permissions available to an IAM entity (IAM roles or IAM users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of wildcards in resource names to accomplish this.

For example, if you include the env terms like "Prod" and "Dev" in all your resources, you can create policies including those terms.

This could be a policy for a Dev role for DynamoDB:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    [
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": "dynamodb:*",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:account-id:*Dev*"
    ],
    [
       "Effect": "Deny",
       "Action": "dynamodb:*",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:account-id:*Prod*"
    ]
  }
}
```

You can do the same for S3 and any other service.

> However, it's easy to forget services.

Without using tags, there isn't an easy way to cover all services with one policy. The wildcard can't be used in the place of the resource itself (ex :`arn:aws:*`)

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_resource.html#reference_policies_elements_resource_wildcards

Comment: I am indeed using this strategy now. I was hoping there was an easier method. Using tags for future resources, and adding tags for existing resources, then seems like a good task to focus on next.